# Concatenating object with list value , Python Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to concatenate python object with list values to append  into another list. But I dont have idea combining this way.

```
my_rec.append("old_date")  # these three are defined date fields
my_rec.append("test_date")
my_rec.append("new_date")



for rec in record.record_ids:                  
            var = "rec."+my_rec[new_date.month-1]
            res.append(var) # it works well with res.append(rec.new_date)
```

but i have two many values to do this like this way

Is there any way to achieve this or any suggestion on this?
Thanks

Comment: What do you want exactly?!!  Your code is impossible go read what are this list and result you want to see

Comment: @Tchi-Odoo, I want to insert values to list at specific index

Comment: Can you describe what you want with example

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using this one-line code:

```
res = [getattr(rec, r) for r in my_rec]
```

**Example:**

```
class Rec:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_field = 'value1'
        self.new_date = 'value2'

rec = Rec()
my_rec = ['test_field', 'new_date']

res = [getattr(rec, r) for r in my_rec]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
['value1', 'value2']
```

Comment: will that append the actual value in the list?

Comment: Which list? `res`? yes, take a look at the content of `res` in the example above

Comment: i mean to say that 'rec.test_field' has a value like 'john' or 'bill'  .

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani I'am not sure I understood your question, but take a look at the above example to see if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution:

```
my_rec.append("test_field") # i have field as 'test_field'

var = getattr(rec, my_rec[0])  # so that it will create 'rec.test_field'

res.append(var)
```

Comment: I tried this, it worked. Can i append value to a particular index? However my list is empty. Like I want to place a value at index 3, while index 1,2 are empty . Since I want to fetch it on my report at particular column I need to set it at at specific index

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani i am unable to understood your question. Can you please give some example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try
var = "rec."+str(my_rec[0])